# position:fixed no scroll bars appearing

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, css-position

I have a `<div>` which is positioned with `position:fixed`. When the window is too small horizontally to fit the div, no scroll bars appear, the right hand side of the div is simply cut off.

If I change to position:absolute, the scroll bars appear as normal.

Is there any way of making the browser recognise the size of the div and the need for scrolling whilst still using position:fixed?

Note:
there is another div with default position declared before the fixed div.

Answer (score 13):

Scrollbars are simply incompatible with a fixed position, logically. If you tell the user-agent to **fix** something, you should not expect scrollbars as they would **move** the something. Why don't you use `position: absolute` as it appears to work for your example?

**Edit**:
@Horizontally-scrollable `div`: From the top of my head, I'd go about something along the lines of the following css (NOTE: I have not tested this, and it is only supposed to give you a rough idea)

```
#myContentWrapper {
  position: absolute; /* here, fixed or relative may work too*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: scroll; /* also, try auto */
}
#myContentWrapper #myContent {
  width: 5000px; /* example */
}
```

With this, if you nest a `div` tag with `id="#myContent"` within `id="$myContentWrapper"`, I believe it may do what you are looking for.

The difference to your approach is, that the *nested* element is large, and the *parent* element is `absolute`/`fixed`/whatever.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Quite obvious really, I should have thought of that.

Is there any way of making a <div> fixed vertically but still scrollable horizontally? I can think of a few very lengthy solutions, but is there something simple?